# Can I connect multiple freelancer-customer pairs with the same twilio number?

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I want to implement a click to call functionality inside my website to anonymously connect freelancers with prospective customers.

Suppose freelancer-A clicks on his browser to call customer-A's phone. At the same time freelancer-B also calls customer-B. 
Do I need multiple twilio numbers as caller ids to do this or one twilio number will suffice?

Please note that the (freelancer-A and customer-A) call and (freelancer-B and customer-B) calls should be separate and this shouldn't be conference call between 4 parties.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You absolutely can do this with just the one number. The question is what you want to happen if the customer A calls the number back. If you want the call to go back through to freelancer A then you would need to set up a relationship between the two users that directs the calls through. Then, if another freelancer were to call customer A, you'd need a new number. This is best handled using [Twilio Proxy](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy) which can manage these relationships and an optimum number pool for you.

If, on the other hand, the call should just come into a central switchboard or even not be connected to anyone, then one number should suffice entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You will need multiple Twilio phone numbers as caller IDs to implement a click-to-call functionality inside your website to anonymously connect freelancers with prospective customers, and ensure that the calls are separate.
This is because Twilio does not allow you to use the same caller ID for multiple concurrent calls. If you try to do this, you will get an error.
One way to implement this is to have a separate Twilio phone number for each freelancer. When a freelancer clicks on the call button to connect with a customer, your website can generate a unique call ID for the call and then use the freelancer's Twilio phone number as the caller ID.

Another way to implement this is to have a pool of Twilio phone numbers that you can assign to freelancers on a rotating basis. When a freelancer clicks on the call button, your website can assign a random Twilio phone number from the pool to the freelancer and then use that phone number as the caller ID.
I hope this helps!